# Add column based on condition in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-cloud-platform, conditional-statements, dynamic-columns

I have 3 columns with values ranging from 0.1 to 0.9.
I want to create a calculated field in sql which would give an output 'Y' if any of the 3 columns has a value greater than 0.8, if not the output should be 'N'. Please see below example -
Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Table example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many DBMS provides **GREATEST()** function to find a max value from given columns, so using it,

```sql
SELECT *, IF(GREATEST(col1, col2, col3) > 0.8, 'Y', 'N') AS calculated_col 
  FROM (
    SELECT 0.8 col1, 0.2 col2, 0.3 col3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.3, 0.3, 0.2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.2, 0.9, 0.5
  );
```

Note : you're mentioning only **greater than 0.8** except **equal to 0.8**, so the below result looks different from yours.

[image]